# Why does Quicksort make n comparisons at each level of recursion?

Tags: algorithm

I think it only needs n-1 comparisons to compare each element in an array except the pivot, i just don't understand partitioning part, any help would be appreciated.
(My question is concerned with the Big O-Notation of Quicksort which is O(nlogn) and I don't understand why it is n? It could it be O((n-1)logn).

Comment: Well in terms of big-oh, *O(n)=O(n-1)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, choosing the pivot is counted as an operation in each recursion and the comparisons are n-1 so each time i do n operation so it's O(nlogn)! thanks for replies.

Comment: It might do more, it doesn't matter, because O(k*n) or O(n+k) where k=const is still O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Following is a passage from the book "Data Structures and Algorithms in Java" by Mark Allen Weiss (Page 31).

> (In terms of Big-Oh). Do not say T(N) = O(2N^2) or T(N) = O(N^2 + N). In both cases, the correct form is T(N) = O(N^2). 
>   Lower-order terms can generally be ignored, and constants can be thrown away. Considerably less precision is required in these cases.